# 5.1 Speakers connected via Optical to LG TV, TV connected to PC via HDMI

Tags: audio, graphics-card, hdmi, tv, sound-card

I have a PC at home that I believe is at least 6 years old. It has [one of these](https://www.mwave.com.au/product/gigabyte-geforce-gtx-750-ti-oc-2gb-low-profile-video-card-ab58983) as the graphics card which I now have connected to my TV via HDMI. I then bought some Logitech 5.1 speakers which I then connected to my TV via Optical cable.The sound from the computer is therefore now coming from pc (you don't say), to the TV, then to the speakers.

My concern however is whether I am truly experiencing  5.1 surround sound? All the speakers surely do produce sound but I'm not sure if the sound is just being spread across all or if it's true surround sound experience. Also, is the sound card even playing a role here (since sound is going through the gpu HDMI)?

Comment: *"My concern however is whether I am truly experiencing 5.1 surround sound?"* -- Despite the punctuation, the wording makes a statement, not a question.  Instead of wondering or guessing, the ideal procedure would be to run a 5.1 sound test which sends sound to only one channel at a time.  *"is the sound card even playing a role here"* -- The audio adapter should still be involved processing audio, because (as you wrote)  *"sound is going through the gpu HDMI"*.  HDMI is simply the audio "output" (path) instead of speakers or headphones.

Comment: [5.1 sound test download](https://www.google.com/search?q=5.1+sound+test+download)

Comment: Okay, I'll test it and get back here